# How can I wait for ajax completed after click button in puppeteer crawler?

Tags: apify

Example:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    $.ajax()...
});
```

Then, I will get all elements on the page to continue to crawl.

Comment: my answer is assuming you want to wait for the ajax to complete before continuing. if it's not the case, please provide more code or context, even real code on what you're trying/tried to do and welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use evaluate callback as an async function, like this:

```js
await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const result = await $.ajax({
    });

    // do something with result here
});
```

the outer `await` on `page.evaluate` will then wait for the ajax to finish before continuing